# create copy of google doc spreadsheet using php api

Tags: php, excel, api, google-docs, google-api-php-client

I want to create copy of excel sheet of google doc using PHP API.I can see java code but no PHP code at all :(

Actually I already have a excel sheet on google drive I want to show it on website, I am already successed in it but problem is The same file is visible to everyone and if one user is changing file and at the same time same user can see that changes as it is synced to google drive.

So I thought solution is if I can create a copy of the sheet and shows different-2 copies to each user via PHP API.

===============

**Edited Code**

```
  function copyFile($service, $originFileId, $copyTitle) {
      $copiedFile = new Google_DriveFile();
      $copiedFile->setTitle($copyTitle);
      try {
        $arr['convert'] =   false;
        $arr['visibility']  =   'default';
        return $service->files->copy($originFileId, $copiedFile,$arr);
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      }
      return NULL;
    }

    function insertPermission($service, $fileId, $value, $type, $role) {
      $newPermission = new Google_Permission();
      $newPermission->setValue($value);
      $newPermission->setType($type);
      $newPermission->setRole($role);
      try {
        return $service->permissions->insert($fileId, $newPermission);
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      }
      return NULL;
    }



    function updateRevision($service, $fileId, $revisionId) {
      try {
        // First retrieve the revision from the API.
        $revisions =    $service->revisions;
        $revision = $revisions->get($fileId, $revisionId);
        echo '<pre>';print_r($revision);
        $revision->setPinned(true);
        return $revisions->update($fileId, $revisionId, $revision);
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
      }
      return NULL;
    }
    function updateRevision1($service, $fileId, $revisionId) {
          $patchedRevision = new Google_Revision();
          $patchedRevision->setPublished(true);
          $patchedRevision->setPublishAuto(true);
          $patchedRevision->setPublishedOutsideDomain(true);
          try {
            return $service->revisions->patch($fileId, $revisionId, $patchedRevision);
          } catch (Exception $e) {
            print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
          }
          return NULL;
        }


    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';


    $client = new Google_Client();
    // Get your credentials from the console
    $client->setClientId('clientid');
    $client->setClientSecret('secret');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
    $client->setRedirectUri('redirecturi');

    $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
    if(!isset($_GET['code']) ) {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('location: '.$authUrl );
    die;
    }
    else{
        $authCode = $_GET['code'];

        // Exchange authorization code for access token
        $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        $new_file   =   copyFile($service,'fileid','Baby Schema');
        echo 'file=<pre>';print_r($new_file);
        $permission  = insertPermission($service,$new_file['id'],'me','anyone','writer'); 
        echo 'permission=<pre>';print_r($permission); 
        $revision   =   updateRevision1($service, $new_file['id'], '1');
        echo 'pub=<pre>';print_r($revision); 
    }
```

Code is working absolutely perfect but it is not doing what I want.

The above code is doing these tasks

```
1) I have one spreadsheet on bhuvneshgupta333@gmail.com
2) I am creating copy when bhuvnesh.gupta@witslog.com login to my abc.com website.
3) I am setting copy to be public on web.
4) Making copy to be published on web.
```

Now I am having issue.

```
1) In the spreadsheet there are 5 sheets out of them 2 are editable and rest 3 are protected so no one can see my formulas.
2) When copy is created by bhuvnesh.gupta@witslog.com then he becomes the owner of file while file is on bhuvneshgupta333@gmail.com while I want Owner to be bhuvneshgupta not bhuvnesh.gupta because I don't want to show formulas to any one not even bhuvnesh.gupta when file is opened on web.
3) I want to protect 3 sheets of spreadsheet to everyone.
```

I am using this way to call spreadhseet on web.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="600" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/fileid/edit?usp=sharing;&rm=minimal"></iframe>
```

Please help me guys.It's last point of my project.

Please help me guys.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The google drive API reference does include PhP code for file copying.

```
/**
  * Copy an existing file.
  *
  * @param Google_DriveService $service Drive API service instance.
  * @param String $originFileId ID of the origin file to copy.
  * @param String $copyTitle Title of the copy.
  * @return DriveFile The copied file. NULL is returned if an API error occurred.
  */
 function copyFile($service, $originFileId, $copyTitle) {
   $copiedFile = new Google_DriveFile();
   $copiedFile->setTitle($copyTitle);
   try {
     return $service->files->copy($originFileId, $copiedFile);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
     print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
   }
   return NULL;
 }
```

It is here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy#try-it

Comment: Yes I have gone through this just now. But I stucked on this variable $service. Please help me in this.

Comment: See if this helps: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php

If the answer solved your problem, please accept it with the green tick. Thanks.

Comment: I went through the url you shared but it did not work. :( Please see my updated question with code. I also tried the same code of file instead of copy function I tried document.txt but it is also not working error on line "STDIN"

Comment: @AkashMishra Let me see. Il get back to you in a bit.

Comment: I have done this but now I am in too much confusion what am I doing.